# Cloning an array of objects in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a script which should fetch some Json data from an API endpoint and do some stuff with it.
Here is what i tried:

```
var dataset

$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/l', function(data) {
  dataset = data

})

console.log(dataset) // Returns undefined
```

The problem with my code is that, right now, i can only use `data` inside the scope of the `$.getJSON` function, while i want that data to be stored on a global variable, which is `dataset`, so that i can use that data on another function. How can i do that? Should i do a loop and push the data from `data` into `dataset` or is there a simpler way?

Here is what my data looks like:

```
"results": [
      { "item": "First",  "id": "1847" .. },
      { "item": "Second", "id": "4442" ..},
      { "item": "Third",  "id": "3847" ..},
      //more records here 
    ]
```

Comment: No matter how you do it, the data will only be available in the callback function, because the function is asynchronous.

Comment: You are assigning the data to `dataset` correctly, but your `console.log` is running before the data is returned.